# Summarize data by group in Plotly R

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have a data frame with animals in two zoo's . Now these animals are repeated. When I plot this using plotly it just takes the one value for the animal and plots it. So even if there are 9 giraffes in `SF_ZOO` it just shows `8`. How can I group by animals and show the sum of all values?

```
library(plotly)

Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys","giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
SF_Zoo <- c(1,4,6,8,9,11)
LA_Zoo <- c(11,13,15,12,15,08)
data <- data.frame(Animals, SF_Zoo, LA_Zoo)

p <- plot_ly(data, x = aggregate(~Animals), y = ~SF_Zoo, type = 'bar', name = 'SF Zoo') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~LA_Zoo, name = 'LA Zoo') %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'group')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `aggregate` correctly; I'd `aggregate` first and then plot

```
data.agg <- aggregate(cbind(SF_Zoo, LA_Zoo) ~ Animals, data = data, FUN = sum)

p <- plot_ly(data.agg, x = ~Animals, y = ~SF_Zoo, type = 'bar', name = 'SF Zoo') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~LA_Zoo, name = 'LA Zoo') %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'group')
```

[image]

Or you could go the `tidyverse` way and use `ggplotly` for plotting

```
library(tidyverse)
p <- data %>%
    gather(Zoo, Value, -Animals) %>%
    group_by(Animals, Zoo) %>%
    summarise(Value = sum(Value)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Animals, y = Value, fill = Zoo)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge2")
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I figured aggregate was the only option. I was wondering if there was an option within plotly to aggregate the data.

Comment: @SNT Not that I'm aware of but I might be wrong; generally speaking I think it's cleaner to separate data aggregation/polishing/tidying and data visualisation.